# Choosing "typical" (median) values to calculate probability in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, logit

Following Hosmer et al. (2013, see below for full reference) I am trying to find estimated probabilities from a logitistic regression controlling for the additional covariates. Hosmer et al. (2013, p. 80-1) proposes to calculate a modified logit "that subtracts the contribution of [the covariates of interest] from the logit and uses its median value as a way to control for the additional covariates". In particular, they propose $$\hat{g}(\textbf{x}) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{2}x_{2}+\beta_{3}x_{3} + \beta_{4}x_{4} + \beta_{5}x_{5} + \beta_{6}x_{6}, \label{eq:1}$$ and then using $$\hat{gm}(\textbf{x})=\hat{g}(\textbf{x})-(\beta_{1}x_{1}+ \beta_{2}x_{2}),$$ where $x_{1}$ and $x_2$ are the independent variables of interest.

My question is how $\hat{gm}$ is calculated if for instance the coeffients were as follows (these are values from the example in the book):

- $\beta_{0}$ -7.695
- $\beta_{1}$ 0.089
- $\beta_{2}$ 1.365
- $\beta_{3}$ 0.083
- $\beta_{4}$ -0.201
- $\beta_{5}$ 0.583
- $\beta_{6}$ -0.791

Hosmer et al. finds $\hat{gm}=-5.349$, but I cannot understand how this value is obtained. Can anyone help me?

So far I have downloaded the dataset from [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/aplore3/man/burn1000.html) and run the regression as described in the book giving me the coefficients mentioned above. I have then calculated the predicted values from the model for each observation in the data set (the median of which is -4.369), say $\textbf{P}$. Then I have calculated the predicted values for $\beta_{1}x_{1}=\textbf{B1}$ and $\beta_{2}x_{2}=\textbf{B2}$ for each observation. Finally, I have calculated $\textbf{P}-(\textbf{B1}+\textbf{B2})=\textbf{A}$, the median of which is -6.707, i.e. not -5.349.

The R script of my efforts so far can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/avrmbla/logisticpredictions/src/5e8e977baedf8e52b5dcc18bb03dc1e4a381e59c/burn1000.R?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

For completeness it should be noted that it seems that they do not advise to use median values of the covariates, as "these values may not provide a logit that is, in some sense, at the median or middle of the log-odds of [the independent variable] for these covariates".

---

Hosmer, David W., Stanley Lemeshow, and Rodney X. Sturdivant. Applied Logistic Regression. Third edition. Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics. Hoboken, New Jersey: Wiley, 2013.

Comment: Well what're the median values for those covariates x1...x6?

Comment: They are x1m=6, x2m=1,x3m=31.95,x4m=2,x5m=2,x6m=2

Comment: and when you do the algebra what answer do you get?

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: @AdamO sorry for bothering you and for my thickness in not understanding your previous comment - can you help me out?